# Pergunta em vias de fechar por duplicata

Tags: debate, perguntas-duplicadas

Eu fiz esta pergunta [Como tornar um site multilíngue?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21788/7210) e o que acontece é que atualmente tem 2 votos para fechar como duplicata. O que acontece é que na parte de cima da pergunta diz:

> Essa pergunta já existe e foi respondida aqui:
>
> [Como traduzir um site em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15937/como-traduzir-um-site-em-php)
>   2 respostas

Eu não acho que seja duplicata, até porque a pergunta é bem diferente, mas mesmo que fosse, acho que é mau aparecer esse tipo de texto até estar fechada, porque quem vê isso de inicio já nem se vai dar ao trabalho de ler a pergunta, pelo menos uma parte das pessoas.

É normal esse comportamento?

Comment: Sim, é normal. Só você vê esse aviso enquanto a pergunta não receber os 5 votos necessários para fechar.

Comment: Obrigado pela informação, estou esclarecido :)

Comment: @bfavaretto eu começo a achar que as pessoas fecham perguntas só porque sim, a minha pergunta nada tem a ver com a outra pergunta. Ainda por cima eu refiro a outra.

Comment: Eu chamei atenção para este problema antes. As pessoas não entendem porque algo deve ser fechado. E pior, há quem sequer olha o que está sendo fechado. Vota porque outros votaram antes. A SE tenta mudar o texto do motivo de fechamento porque ele é mal usado, aí o novo texto continua sendo mal usado por outras razões. O problema não está no texto. O problema está nas pessoas que não entendem ou não querem entender a ferramenta.

Comment: Tem mesmo muita gente fechando "só porque sim". Mas essa sua pergunta é um caso mais complicado, pois a resposta que tem na outra é *quase* uma resposta à sua. Pensei bastante no assunto e neste momento tendo a não considerar duplicata mesmo assim. A comunidade parece ter deixado a pergunta em paz também. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Após um certo número de votos para fechar (acredito que 2), o autor da pergunta passa a ver o tal aviso *Essa pergunta já existe e foi respondida aqui*. Enquanto a pergunta está aberta, somente o autor vê esse aviso no topo. Os demais usuários vêem somente o comentário automático *Possível duplicata de...*.

Caso a pergunta seja efetivamente fechada, todos passam a ver o aviso no topo, e o comentário automático é removido.