# Pergunta fechada mas continua aberta?

Tags: suporte, fechamento, sinalização, perguntas-fechadas

Recentemente criei uma pergunta aqui no SOPt, a pergunta pode ser vista [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124436/como-%C3%A9-desenvolvida-uma-linguagem-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o/). Nela há um voto para fechamento por não estar clara para o entendimento porém, apenas para mim,  aparece que a pergunta está fechada com o motivo de já existente no Stack.

A imagem em tamanho real está [aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sibF3.jpg).

Isso pode ser `bug`? Já que apenas aparece para mim e não mais para ninguém.

Texto Vísivel apenas para mim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha pergunta não está fora do escopo da comunidade do Stack Over Flow, não entendo porque poderia ser fechada, acredito que seja de bom uso para todos de dentro e fora da SOPt por ser uma "agregadora" de conhecimento.

A diferença dessa pergunta com a [possível duplicata de pergunta em vias de fechar por duplicata](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1566/pergunta-em-vias-de-fechar-por-duplicata) é que no meu caso, as informações estão bagunçadas e eu não consigo achar o real motivo. Os votos para fechar são por ampla demais e ela está marcando fechamento por possível duplicata.

Comment: @JorgeB. a pergunta não está votada como duplicata, só como ampla.

Comment: @bigown tem 1 voto como duplicata.

Comment: @JorgeB. Só vejo 2 de ampla. Você pode por uma tela com o voto?

Comment: @bigown seleciona a opção duplicata e vê.

Comment: @JorgeB. Mas o voto não está lá. Alguém pode ter votado antes.

Comment: @bigown "@VictorGomes não adianta ficar criticando as pessoas, eles ajudam muito a comunidade, por isso vem marcada como "possivel duplicata(...)" disse o Guilherme Nascimento.

Comment: @JorgeB. Mas o voto não existe mais. Só tem os 2 de ampla. A mensagem continuar lá está causando a maior confusão. No mínimo ela é *misleading*. Se é pra deixar ela lá, tinha que ficar claro que alguém votou anteriormente nisso, pra pessoa avaliar, mas que o voto não existe mais. Ou sumir com ela. Se não é *bug*  deve ser um *feature request*. E essa não é duplicata, é o mesmo assunto, mas outro problema.

Comment: Exatamente @bigown, pode ser o mesmo assunto mas a situação é diferente. Enquanto a pergunta no SOPt, acredito que não seja ampla demais, lendo a descrição da pergunta, comentários e a própria resposta do `bigown`  da pra entender com certeza, o que a pergunta quer dizer. Ficou até engraçado eu criar uma aqui no Meta escrevendo sobre a duplicata errada e essa também foi marcada como duplicada. Estou tendo problema com originalidade haha

Comment: @bigown Para mim ainda aparece um voto para fechar como duplicada http://imgur.com/atQCXk6

Comment: @jbueno mas ele não existe mais, só tem 2 votos na pergunta e eles são de ampla.

Comment: @bigown pra mim também não aparece, acho que o primeiro voto não aparece na lista, se eu seleciono pra duplicar então aparece. Isso não é a primeira vez que vejo ocorrer, por isso acho que talvez seja confusão no entendimento. Mas nada impede de ser um bug.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o problema é que as mensagens do sistema não deixam claro o que está acontecendo, aí começa gerar um monte de confusão.

Comment: @bigown foi mais ou menos o que quis dizer, confusão no entendimento justamente porque o sistema é confuso

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu explico o mistério: a pergunta tem uma sinalização do tipo "recomendar fechamento", que só existe para quem ainda não tem a pontuação necessária para votar para fechar. Por conta dessa sinalização, o autor (e apenas ele) passa a ver esse cabeçalho, conforme já explicado em [Pergunta em vias de fechar por duplicata](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1566/pergunta-em-vias-de-fechar-por-duplicata).